# button for next is not working, not recognizing the required in input type radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

The form has validation, if left unanswered the next button cannot be clicked.
However, in my code even if the fields are left unanswered, next button can be clicked. Validation is not recognized.

this is a part of my code for the buttons.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  var form_count = 1, previous_form, next_form, total_forms;
  total_forms = $("fieldset").length;  
  $(".next-form").click(function(){
        previous_form = $(this).parent();
        next_form = $(this).parent().next();
        next_form.show();
        previous_form.hide();
        setProgressBarValue(++form_count);
  });
```

Here is the code:

```
<form action="applicantAssessmentSave.php" method="post" id="register_form">

       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="finished_degree" style="color:#fff";>Finished Degree</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="finished_degree" id="finished_degree"   onchange= "handleSelectChange(event)" required>
         <option value="" selected disabled >Select your finished degree</option>
         <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
         <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
         <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
                                            
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleSelectChange(event){
         var selectElement = event.target;
         var value = selectElement.value;

            $.ajax({
                url:"degree_job_match.php", 
            type: "post",    
            data: {
                "value": $('#finished_degree').val(),
            }, 
            success:function(data){
            }
        });
     }
    </script>
    </div>
        <?php
            $m = 1;
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from question_categories") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $question = mysqli_query($con, "select * from question where cat_id='".$id."' ") or die(mysqli_error($con));   
                ?>  
        <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="cat_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
             <div class="card" style="background-color: #fff; " > 
             <div class="card-body" style="margin-left: 20px;">
             <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <?php 
          while ($question_row = mysqli_fetch_array($question)) {
         ?>
           <input type="hidden" name="question_id[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>">     
        <div class="form-group">
         <label style="font-weight: 900;">
           <strong>
            <?php echo $question_row['question']; ?>
           </strong>
         </label>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="5" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Strongly Agree
        </label>
       </div>
    <br>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="4" required>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        Agree
    </label>
</div>
    <br>
    

    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="3" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
        Neutral
        </label>
        </div>
       <br>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="2" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Disgree
        </label>
       </div>
         <br>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="1" required>
            <label class="form-check-label">
              Strongly Disagree
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        </div>
       <?php } ?>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
              <?php if($m!=$count){ ?>
                <button name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary next-form btn-sm" type="button" style="background-color: #fff200; color:#000;">
                 Next
                 </button>
                <?php } if($m!=1){ ?>
                 <button name="" id="" class="btn btn-warning previous-form" type="button">
                  Previous
                 </button>
                <?php } ?>
                 <?php if($m==$count){ ?>
                    <button  class="btn btn-info submit" id="submit_form">
                       Submit
                    </button>
                    <?php } ?>
          </fieldset>
             <?php
                    $m++;
         }
         ?>
      </form>
```

What I wanted to do is validate first if radio button are selected in each question, then button next will show the next set of questions. But in this code, it does not validate and just show the next set of questions even if the first set is not answered.

Comment: Please include your html code, without we can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Also I don't see any code that would text for validation.

Comment: I updated my code, I dont know how to do validation in that part.

Answer (score 0):

simply with the `form.checkValidity()` function in the button click event

Comment: Nothing happens. I think there should be a code inside next-form but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: in the click handler you have to check if `form.checkValidity()` is true so the next-form will be performed or false to stay on the current form and tell user that the form is invalid

Comment: I dont know if I understand it well 
i did this but nothings happen

`$(".next-form").click(function(){
   if(form.checkValidity() == true){
  previous_form = $(this).parent();
  next_form = $(this).parent().next();
  next_form.show();
  previous_form.hide();
  setProgressBarValue(++form_count);
   }
  }); `

Comment: You have to check `else` in your `if` statement and `return false` from within a jQuery event handler.

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and `return false` will do both. Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, `return false` does not stop the event from bubbling up.